# Using Ruby Selenium to input data from csv file to complete actions until list is complete

Tags: ruby, csv, selenium-webdriver, rspec

I am fairly new to selenium ruby/rspec scripting and I have come across a use case that requires data to be pulled from a csv or xlsx file in the test. Any help or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

The test would pull from the csv file and input data from each row to complete the same actions against. This particular file contains a single column of "id's" and the same action would need to be repeated until all values from the column have been used. Here is the basic steps...

1. User logs in
2. User pulls first value (id) from file to search in text field
3. User completes action against this id
4. User returns to text field and pulls value from second row of same file
5. User completes action against this id

This would repeat until all rows are completed

Is this possible to complete the same method repeatedly but filtering through data from the file?

How would you pull the csv file into the script and specifically grab the first value (and subsequent values) throughout?

I know this is pretty vague but I have not seen any examples such as this in SO and researching online. Any suggestions or examples would very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I can try to point you in the right direction.

Ruby has a csv parser built in which you can read about here: [CVS class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

One of the first examples would seem to provide you with the functinoality you are looking for. I think in your example you would want to do something like:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  #I'm assuming ID is the first element in each row
  id = row.first
  method_that_does_stuff(id)

  # assert that stuff has happened ...
end
```

does that help get you started?

Comment: Thanks Jonny that does help me get started. How would I be able to loop this though once the assertion is complete, so that I could return to the first page and submit the value in the next row to complete that method? For example I would need to return to "Step 2" to enter the value in row 2 and so on and so on. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Put all that navigation logic inside of method_that_does_stuff(). So inside of that method you could log in, put id in text field, and completes action agains id. Then you assert that this is correct and then the loop starts again. There are pitfalls to this approach as your test could die early and then any assertions following the failure will not run. I suppose you could log a result after each loop and then assert outside of the foreach.